# How can I center the titles in the table?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I have the following table in `LaTex`. How can I center `ABC` and `DEF`?

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|}
\hline
\centerline {i}
 &    \multicolumn{2}{l|}{ABC} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{DEF} \\
\hline
&&&& \\
\hline
&&&& \\
\hline
&&&& \\
\hline
&&&& \\
\hline
&&&& \\
\hline
&&&& \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Use `c|` instead of `l|`. Also, for `i`, use `\centering i`.

Comment: Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) is the preferred way here to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 1):

The different table alignment options (l, c, r, p, m, b) are described by [Wikibooks link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#The_tabular_environment).

Using Werner's comment, the answer is

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|}
\hline
\centering i
 &    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ABC} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{DEF} \\
\hline
&&&& \\
\hline
&&&& \\
\hline
&&&& \\
\hline
&&&& \\
\hline
&&&& \\
\hline
&&&& \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```